# Set number of threads for each section in openmp?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

I wonder if it is possible to set number of threads for each section in an openmp parallel section i.e.:

```
real*8     :: x
real*4     :: y
integer*8  :: ii
integer*4  ** jj
x = 0.0d0
y = 0.0
!$OMP PARALLEL 
!$OMP SECTIONS
!$OMP SECTION NUM_THREADS(3)
do ii=1,100000000000
  x=x+(cos(sin(tan(ii*1.0d0)))**(x/ii)
end do
!$OMP SECTION NUM_THREADS(1)
do jj=1,10000
  x=x+exp(jj*0.001)
end do
!$OMP END SECTIONS
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

This code does not work with ifort 16.0 but I just wonder if there is something else one could do..?

EDIT: I get an error (during compilation) when I try to set number of threads per section... I would like to specify different number of threads per section.

EDIT 2:Error message = 2 x

> error #5082: Syntax error, found 'NUM_THREADS' when expecting one of "<"END-OF-STATEMENT">" ;

at the two `!OMP SECTION NUM_THREADS(i)`statements

Pardon the hasty writ..

Comment: What does it mean *"This code does not work"*? It does not tell anything at all. Wrong results? How do they look like? Why are they wrong? Some error messages? How do they look like? How does your compilation command look like? What does it have in common with the title (setting the number of threads)?

Comment: @Vladimir F - thanks for the quick reply - I hope my edit made it clearer

Comment: What is this code trying to do? It has race conditions on 'x', and the point of "sections" is to execute the two sections in parallel, which seems wrong too. Don't you just want a parallel, then two omp for loops each with a reduction clause? (Though the first loop has a loop carried dependence, so can't easily parallelize!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've told us what we needed to know it's blindingly obvious what the problem is ...

... the `num_threads` clause is applicable only to the `parallel` directive.

It is not possible to, in a straightforward fashion, allocate `m` out of `n` threads to one section and the remaining `n-m` threads to another.  You can probably hack something together to achieve that effect but it would be going against the grain of OpenMP programming.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is against the philosophy of OpenMP, where you are not supposed to have full control on threads. You can, however, use a hack: a combination of OpenMP and pthread. That is, OMP PARALLEL blocks which contain pthread statements (pthread will give you full control on which threads will be used in the OMP block). In the past, I was experimenting with that, and although I didn't try exactly what you want to do, I managed to get some interesting results verifying that a OpenMP+pthread combination is possible. Besides, some compilers (like gfortran) implement OpenMP via pthreads behind the scenes.

Of course you need to write Fortran bindings for the pthread statements you will use, but that's not much of a problem. The real problem is that such an approach is problematic by definition. It mixes two radically different parallelization models and it is a hack, so you are on your own. I wouldn't go that way in a serious application but, with enough trial-and-error, it is a way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: It does not have to be that complicated. Nested OpenMP is much easier.